# Is having different implementations for ToString and the implicit operator bad design?

Tags: c#, api

I am currently developing a wrapper API for a translation service that should provide multiple methods for translating `string`s,

```
Task<string> ITranslator.TranslateAsync(string phrase, Language from, Language to)
```

an `ICollection<string>`,

```
Task<ICollection<string>> ITranslator.TranslateAsync(ICollection<string> phrases, Language from, Language to)
```

and entire documents:

```
Task<Stream> ITranslator.TranslateDocumentAsync(string file, Language from, Language to)
```

The `Language` class looks as follows

```
public sealed class Language
{
    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string TwoLetterISOLanguageName { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string NativeName { get; internal set; }

    internal Language()
    {
    }

    /* Provided in case users want to display these in a ComboBox or similar. */
    public override string ToString() => NativeName;
}
```

and instances of the class can only be acquired by a call to `ITranslator.GetSupportedLanguagesAsync`.

However, I don't want to force users of the API to query the supported languages and additionally provide a less verbose way of making translation requests with methods that take `from` and `to` parameters of type `string` instead of `Language`, where the provided string would be a language code such as `"de"`.

My issue with that solution is that it would lead to the doubling of Translate* methods and thus unnecessarily clutter the API and duplicate most of the documentation regarding these methods.

I finally thought about introducing an `implicit operator` function to the `Language` class which would convert instances to their `TwoLetterISOLanguageCode` and remove the need for method overloads, but I am unsure if it would be bad design, as the `Language` class already has the `ToString` method yielding `NativeName` instead.

Would this addition of the `implicit operator` be bad design?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the goal here but would it not be more intuitive to use something like a dictionary in your case? Possibly something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233536/c-sharp-store-functions-in-a-dictionary

Comment: The built-in code for globalization in C# uses `CultureInfo`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8  which encapsulates number formats, date formats, language specification, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A string is a totally unsuitable data structure to identify a language. That's because you'd have to specify how to interpret the text in the string (out of "French", "französisch", "franzoesisch", "Français", "Francais", "FR", which specify a language?), and it is not clear at all whether a string represents a language or not.

So your application should translate user-entered strings specifying languages in the locale of the user, or other strings supposed to specify languages, into "Language" instances at the earliest point possible, getting either a valid instance of Language or not, and handling the problem where a string didn't represent a language at the earliest possible point.

And now your whole problem is gone.

In the "Language" class itself, it is absolutely not clear what a method returning a string for a Language object would be supposed to return. If you have a function returning the two letter ISO code, name it so the caller knows it returns the two letter ISO code. Many languages have a standard function to generate a string to be used for logging / debugging purposes.

"NativeName" is already unclear: Are the "NativeName"s of English, French and German "English", "Français", and "Deutsch" (because these *are* their native names)? Or did you mean localized names which might be "Anglais", "Français", and "Allemand", if the user is French?

If you try to do some automatic conversion you just make this problem an awful lot worse.

Comment: My issue with converting strings into a Language object at the earliest time is that I don't know what is a supported language until a call to `ITranslator.GetSupportedLanguagesAsync`, as it's only a wrapper and the service might implement new languages.


Thanks for the feedback regarding the NativeName property. I'll make sure to properly document that it specifies the actual native names, meaning "English", "Français" and "Deutsch" in your example.

Comment: @AndreB. Any application is going to want to call `GetSupportedLanguagesAsync` pretty close to startup anyway, to populate the UI for language selection. Even a command line program will likely want to populate a message when given `foobar --lang=klingon`.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, the correct way to specify a language in an API is an enum. An enum is an exhaustive list of discrete values. This also acts as a guardrail at compile time, because unsupported values can't compile. There will be an impedance mismatch because JSON doesn't have enums, but JSON libraries can up/downconvert from string to enum.

ToString() has acquired a bit of a code smell because the intention for the string representation is not stated. Is it for logging, debugging, or for display to the end user? If it's needed for display, I'd include a *DisplayName* member to increase readability of the code. You might also need to localize that.

In no way shape or form should the caller have to concern itself with the full contents of your Language class. You would instead keep a dictionary to retrieve the Language instance, as so

```
public enum LanguageIdentifier {
    en,
    de // more ISO identifiers you support ...
}

internal class Language {
    LanguageIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public static class Translator {
    internal static Dictionary<LanguageIdentifier, Language> LanguageMap = 
        new Dictionary<LanguageIdentifier, Language>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's against guidelines**

Not all strings are valid languages, and casting one could result in a run-time error. According to the MS [guidelines for casting types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/5b63aadf(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> Do not throw exceptions from implicit casts because it is very difficult for the developer to understand what is happening.

Since your implicit operator could throw, it's probably not a great design.

As an alternative I would suggest a static `From___` pattern, e.g.

```
translator.TranslateAsync(text, Language.FromCultureString("en-us"), Language.FromCultureString("tlh"));
```

If you're married to the idea of an implicit conversion, maybe you could provide one for Culture (assuming there is a complete mapping from culture to language), which would allow the caller to do this:

```
translator.TranslateAsync(text, new Culture("en-us"), new Culture("tlh"));
```

Answer (score 0):

ToString() is meant only to convey one thing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

Using it the Language class probably goes against it's original intention.

You might want to use it to describe the language being used.  For example it could return:  EN "English" or FR "French".